# Special characters

Tags: keyboard

After upgrading to 13.10 I cannot enter special characters anymore. So I cannot write either French or French special characters (that are not directly available in the French or the German keyboards)

I tried to change the configuration of the keyboard using the following command `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

But to no avail for right ALT remains dead.
I tried also to change via he system settings again to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Select the correct keyboard - see 'layout settings' or 'input sources', select the one with the special characters.

[image: keyboard settings]

[image]

[image: special characters]

This is in Gnome 3.8 *(the top pic is off the internet)*, so it might be a bit different to yours. On my computer, both the French and German keyboards settings have special characters.